# Flink Web Dashboard job submission hanging

Tags: dashboard, apache-flink

I am able to run example flink jobs & my basic stream calculations.
Just trying to run a relatively complex IterativeStream calculation jar through Flink web dashboard and it keeps on hanging even for 'Show Plan'.

Can't see anything logged as well, any suggestions how to debug this.

I am able to run same program through IDE and below is plan visualization JSON ->

```
{"nodes":
    [{"id":-1,"type":"IterationSource-2","pact":"Data Source","contents":"IterationSource-2","parallelism":1},
        {"id":1,"type":"Source: BOND_PRICING_CONFIG","pact":"Data Source","contents":"Source: BOND_PRICING_CONFIG","parallelism":1},
        {"id":3,"type":"Source: TW_CHAIN_DATA_SOURCE","pact":"Data Source","contents":"Source: TW_CHAIN_DATA_SOURCE","parallelism":1},
        {"id":4,"type":"Map","pact":"Operator","contents":"Map","parallelism":4,"predecessors":[{"id":3,"ship_strategy":"REBALANCE","side":"second"}
    ]},
    {"id":5,"type":"Filter","pact":"Operator","contents":"Filter","parallelism":4,"predecessors":[{"id":4,"ship_strategy":"FORWARD","side":"second"}]},
    {"id":6,"type":"TW_PRICING_FILTER","pact":"Operator","contents":"TW_PRICING_FILTER","parallelism":4,"predecessors":
        [{"id":1,"ship_strategy":"REBALANCE","side":"second"},{"id":-1,"ship_strategy":"REBALANCE","side":"second"}]},
        {"id":9,"type":"TW_PRICE_COPIER","pact":"Operator","contents":"TW_PRICE_COPIER","parallelism":4,"predecessors":
            [{"id":6,"ship_strategy":"HASH","side":"second"},{"id":5,"ship_strategy":"HASH","side":"second"}]},
            {"id":10,"type":"TW_PRICE_TO_YIELD","pact":"Operator","contents":"TW_PRICE_TO_YIELD","parallelism":4,"predecessors":
                [{"id":9,"ship_strategy":"FORWARD","side":"second"}]},
                {"id":12,"type":"TW_REDUCE_DUPLICATE","pact":"Operator","contents":"TW_REDUCE_DUPLICATE","parallelism":4,"predecessors":
                    [{"id":10,"ship_strategy":"HASH","side":"second"}]},
                    {"id":-2,"type":"IterationSink-2","pact":"Data Sink","contents":"IterationSink-2","parallelism":1,"predecessors":
                        [{"id":1,"ship_strategy":"FORWARD","side":"second"},{"id":-1,"ship_strategy":"FORWARD","side":"second"}]},
                        {"id":13,"type":"Sink: Unnamed","pact":"Data Sink","contents":"Sink: Unnamed","parallelism":4,"predecessors":
                            [{"id":12,"ship_strategy":"FORWARD","side":"second"}]}]}
```

Comment: You'd better have a look at the JobManager log to find a clue.

Comment: Nothing in logs, realized there was a blocking call at startup for external connection which was preventing it. Moved connection logic to be executed at stream source processing level and worked!